# How to redirect a fixed folder name to another fixed folder, regardless of where it is requested

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have the current situation in my web application:

The html files, will request images from the let's say {currentpath}/images/

Because of using an MVC my URL's change often:

```
domain.com/app/main/welcome/
```

(to get the welcome method from the main class)

In this situation, the view will request images from

```
domain.com/app/main/welcome/images/
```

I would need that in any situation, if a script calls for something from it's images subfolder, to be redirected to a fixed folder (let's say domain.com/app/images/).

So far, I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/app/(.*)/images/(.*)$ $1/app/images/$3 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Which doesn't work.

My intention is to redirect:

```
domain.com/app/{anything}/images/
```

to

```
domain.com/app/images/{the requested image}
```

It is my first post in stackoverflow, usually I find all the answers straight by search, but on this I don't know how to do it.

Btw, I know I could simply do a replace_all on all my views with the fixed path, but as it might change in the future, this would be a much more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?app/.+/images/(.*)$ /app/images/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

You might want to decide on how you want the urls to permanently be though and just change the redirects to match and just change the rest in the background. You might want to consider Alias as well:

... where {currentpath} has to be filled in

```
Alias /app/{currentpath}/images /app/images
```

or AliasMatch

```
AliasMatch ^/app/.+/images(.*) /app/images$1
```

and then change the last part when the folder changes, you can also permanently redirect through mod_alias although it's a little different:

```
Redirect 301 /app/{currentpath}/images http://domain.com/app/images
```

There is also a RedirectMatch as well.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Both solutions worked, but I remained with the AliasMatch as it seems more elegant.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The rule that you need is this:

```
RewriteRule ^(app/)[^/]+/(images/.*)$ $1$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```